# Currying with bind function and to correctly type with generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, generics, typescript-generics, currying

I have written a sort function and would like to bind a compare function to it. Unfortunately, the TypeScript compiler warns me for `unknown` type for the compare function.

I have tried search for [SO: Bind function to function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+bind+function+of+function)
and search in [TS Handbook: bind](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function). However, I cannot find any related issue.

And tried to follow the type in the declaration file:

```js
    /**
     * For a given function, creates a bound function that has the same body as the original function.
     * The this object of the bound function is associated with the specified object, and has the specified initial parameters.
     * @param thisArg The object to be used as the this object.
     * @param args Arguments to bind to the parameters of the function.
     */
    bind<T>(this: T, thisArg: ThisParameterType<T>): OmitThisParameter<T>;
    bind<T, A0, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, AX, R>(this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
```

```
function sorting<T>(a: T, fn: (v0: T, v1: T) => number,  b: T) {
  return fn(a, b)
}

sorting<number>.bind(null, 1, (a, b) => a + b)
//               ^ Cannot find name 'bind'.(2304)

sorting.bind<null, number, (v0: number, v1: number) => number, [b: number]>(null, 1, (a, b) => a + b)
//^ Argument of type '(b: number) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type //'(v0: number, v1: number) => number'.
//  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJ1mA5gHgCoB8AFAIYBcieANIsGBUQG4AMF1ijAjGwJSIC8BRGBABbAEYBTNDUTjeiAN4AoRIjSSoINEjqka4nsoC+y5agwxsOEROkEAdOKsATIiIA2Hmpxr65fIKIJIgA1AFmFphYTq42IF40tlIyiEyswmIpNFwUydKBQvmpANrymXZoALrEnt6IvmkkBoXBYRFAA)

And it still does not work. Am I missing something here? Why I can not `bind` arguments `a` and `fn`?

---

P.S.

Currently I used arrow function to curry the sort function as a work around.

Comment: This is possible in the next version of TypeScript [with instantiation expressions](https://tsplay.dev/mLlkVm). 4.7 comes around soon. Just wait a week or two ;)

Comment: @catgirlkelly That's great! I'm glad that there will be an update for this issue. I believe it is the answer. Do you consider leaving an `answer` below so that I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a common problem, and so common that it is being fixed in the next minor version of TypeScript (4.7)! The solution that is being used is called an [instantiation expression](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#instantiation-expressions).

Here's their example:

```
interface Box<T> {
    value: T;
}

function makeBox<T>(value: T) {
    return { value };
}
```

While you could do this:

```
const makeStringBox = (value: string) => makeBox(value); // makeBox<string>(value: string)
```

It is quite wasteful, so 4.7 introduces new syntax:

```
const makeStringBox = makeBox<string>; // type parameters passed without calling it!
```

This also means you can pass it to `sorting` before binding it:

```
// works in 4.7+ now!
(sorting<number>).bind(null, 1, (a, b) => a + b)
```

You can try the nightly version of TypeScript (4.8+) [here with this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-dev.20220518#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJ1mA5gHgCoB8AFAIYBcieANIsGBUQG4AMF1ijAjGwJSIC8BRGBABbAEYBTNDUTjeiAN4AoRIjSSoINEjqka4nsoC+y5agwxsOEROkEAdOKsATIiIA2Hmpxr65fIKIJIgA1AFmAPSRKOiYWE6uNiBeNLZSMohMrMJiGTRcFOnSgULFmQDa8rl2aAC6xJ7eiL5ZJAalwWERQA).

Comment: just a small  note: I needed cracket the function and the type:
`(sorting<number>).bind(null, 1, (a, b) => a + b)`